# How to serve two wsgi from localhost subdomains

Tags: apache, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi, pyramid

The application I am working on has two servers: One APi and another App. Both are created using pyramid and the plan is to put them on at least two separate machines.

But for my laptop I want to be able to map api.localhost to api server and app.localhost to the app server

I have done the following:

This is my httpd.conf file:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid user=ranjith group=staff processes=1 \
   threads=4 \
   python-path=/home/ranjith/VENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ranjith/workspace/app.wsgi  
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ranjith/workspace/api.wsgi  
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /home/ranjith/VENV>
  WSGIProcessGroup pyramid
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I Added these entries in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       api.localhost
127.0.0.1       app.localhost
```

Added two WSGI files for the servers. They work as they work on the dev servers

But I really do not know how to configure localhost subdomain and I do not have any real knowledge of WSGI.

I did sudo service apache2 restart

It says:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2

apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName                                                                                              
... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
```

Which is not an error message I think.

When I type: http://app.localhost, I am not able to visit the app as I get a 404 error

Now what is wrong with my httpd.conf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a subdomain then. Use 'api-localhost' and 'app-localhost' instead.

Separate to that:

```
<Directory /home/ranjith/VENV>
  WSGIProcessGroup pyramid
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

is wrong. Should be:

```
<Directory /home/ranjith/workspace>
  WSGIProcessGroup pyramid
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Otherwise the WSGIProcessGroup is never used and you will be running in embedded mode and not daemon mode.